# Linux How can I prove if udev installed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

How can I prove if udev is installed and working proper?  Just call udevadm would be a method, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the udev daemon `udevd` is running:

```
if [[ $(pgrep -c udevd) -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No udev"
else
    echo "udev is running"
fi
```

Or check the output of `service udev status` which contains `start/running` if udev is running.

Answer (score 2):

If you what to test your udev is running and working. do following to verify.

Delete one of devices from /dev

```
rm /dev/fd0
```

Run udevtrigger, it will auto create missing device again.

```
/sbin/udevtrigger
```

Comment: @ Satish  Thanks for the answer, just one problem with your solution. If I delete the device and udev is not running, the device is gone :)

Answer (score 1):

@Peter - If device is gone you can create them back using following command.

```
[root@mg0016 ~]# mknod /tmp/fd0 b 2 0
[root@mg0016 ~]# ls -l /tmp/fd0
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 2, 0 Sep  7 10:09 /tmp/fd0
```